# why video background is not working in mobile devices?

Tags: video, html5-video

I have been using HTML5 video background on my website. It's working good in computer, but it's not working on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What device did you use? And what type of that video? Is it automatic video play?
If the device is Ipad or Iphone and the video is automatic video play, you'd need a play/stop/pause button because the iPad doesn't support automatic video play. ^^
Btw, you must check the resizing of that video. Because it may be the reason made the video didn't run!

Comment: I am using youtube video. The page and the background video all are responsive only. But It does not working in mobile device.